# How to know maximum at an irregular tree?

Tags: haskell

I have an irregularly defined tree, how can i run through it and find the maximum value in it?

My strategy was to build a list and take out the bigger value, my problem is, i only know binary trees, where i have the left and the right, like this: `Node x Empty Empty`

I have this structure now:

```
tree= No 2 [No 3 [No 6 []], No 4 [No 7 [], No 8 []], No 5 []]

data TreeIrr a = No a [TreeIrr a]
```

How is it supposed to be traversed?

this is the best i could do:

```
maxi :: ArvIrr a -> [a]
maxi (No a []) = [a]
maxi (No a l@((No b []):z)) = [a]++[b]++(maxis l)
                    where
                     maxis ((No x k):(No y z):ls) = [y]++maxis ls
maxi (No a [k]) = [a]++(maxi k)
```

Comment: The easy way that doesn't involve much learning is to use `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}` at the top of your file, then `import qualified Data.Foldable as F`, then `data TreeIrr a = No a [TreeIrr a] deriving (F.Foldable)`.  You can now do `F.maximum tree`.  If you want to learn some more, [read the wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldable_and_Traversable#Foldable) and then start googling around for more information on foldable and traversable.  They're very useful typeclasses.

Comment: A less easy way that might be a little bit more illuminating is to write your own `treeFold` function and then do something along the lines of `treeFold max t`

Comment: @bheklilr thank you very much for the tip, but i need to know how to do this manually. 
i discovered now that they are called "rose trees"!

Comment: Are you trying to find the maximum in your `maxi` function or convert it into a list so you can use `maximum`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a simple recursive dfs-like traversal:

```
data TreeIrr a = No a [TreeIrr a]

findMax :: Ord a => TreeIrr a -> a
findMax (No x []) = x     -- For a tree without subtrees the maximum is it's value
findMax ( No x subtrees ) =
    maximum ( x : map findMax subtrees)      -- For a tree with subtrees the maximum is the maximum among it's root value or the maximum of it's subtrees
```

and then

```
>> findMax (No 2 [No 3 [No 6 []], No 4 [No 7 [], No 8 []], No 5 []])
8
```

Upd:
 After a little thinking, the base case is redundant here. So
just

```
findMax :: Ord a => TreeIrr a -> a
findMax ( No x subtrees ) = maximum ( x : map findMax subtrees)
```

will work fine

Answer (score 4):

```
data TreeIrr a = No a [TreeIrr a]
```

The maximum element of such a tree is the maximum of two values:

1. The element at the root note.
2. The maximum of the maximums of its children.

Therefore:

```
treeMaximum :: Ord a => TreeIrr a -> a
treeMaximum (No a []) = a
treeMaximum (No a children) = max a (maximum (map treeMaximum children))
```

Where `max :: Ord a => a -> a -> a`, and `maximum :: Ord a => [a] -> a` are standard library functions.

Comment: Pretty, and simple, and altogether nice.

Answer (score 3):

Let's pretend we have a traversal function:

```
maxi :: ArvIrr a -> [a]
```

How should we extend this to a *list* of trees?

```
maxiList :: [ArvIrr a] -> [a]
```

Well, we could use a `map`:

```
maxiList l = map maxi l  -- WRONG type [[a]]
```

but we get a lists of lists instead of a single list. No problem, let's concatenate them all.

```
maxiList l = concat (map maxi l)
```

OK, now let's assume we have `maxiList` working, and build `maxi` in terms of it. This is quite simple:

```
maxi (No a l) = a : maxiList l
```

So, putting everything together:

```
maxi :: ArvIrr a -> [a]
maxi (No a l) = a : maxiList l
maxiList :: [ArvIrr a] -> [a]
maxiList l = concat (map maxi l)
```

We can further simplify it by removing `maxiList` and inlining it.

```
maxi :: ArvIrr a -> [a]
maxi (No a l) = a : concat (map maxi l)
```

And `concat (map maxi l)` can be rewritten as `concatMap maxi l`,
exploiting the `concatMap` library function.

```
maxi :: ArvIrr a -> [a]
maxi (No a l) = a : concatMap maxi l
```

To compute the maximum, you can use

```
maxInTree :: Ord a => ArvIrr a -> a
maxInTree t = maximum (maxi t)
```

If you want, you can further simplify this code so that the intermediate list is not even built, and the maximum is computed directly. This is probably a bit challenging for a Haskell beginner, but it might be fun. Start by replacing `concat` in the code above ...

Comment: _Technically_ `concat . map` won't typecheck, so I'd change it to "And `concat . map f` is called `concatMap f` in the library." or "And `\f -> concat . map f` is called `concatMap` in the library.", but it would be really pedantic and picky to bring up that point in the first place.